# Setting summary info in MST using WIX

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

The MST created using wix does not have updated summary information stream values.

```
//The temp msi (copy of original msi) has updated summary info values
Database d2 = new Database(tempmsiPath, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct);

//origDatabase is a Database object of original msi;
d2.GenerateTransform(origDatabase, mstPath);

//this code is used to create the mst. 
d2.CreateTransformSummaryInfo(origDatabase, mstPath, 
                TransformErrors.None,TransformValidations.None);
```

Please let me know how i can implement the writing updated summary values to MST using C#.

Answer (score 1):

If I open an MSI in ORCA, create a new transform and then go to Summary Information all of the fields are greyed out.

If I then go to (in ORCA) Transform | Transform Properties I get a screen titled "Transform SummaryInfo".  It has a series of checkboxes for suppress errors and validation.  This maps to the arguments available in CreateTransformSummaryInfo.   Reading the DTF help topic on the same method says:

> Creates and populates the summary information stream of an existing
>   transform file, and fills in the properties with the base and
>   reference ProductCode and ProductVersion.

There is also a TranformInfo class in ....WindowsInstaller.Package assembly but it only supports reading transform information.   Rob might be able to tell you more but it seems pretty much by design to not give unrestricted access.  Probably because the transform has to be compatible with the base MSI.

Maybe if I understood exactly what/why you are updating I could give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply .I need to create mst template with standards for any msi hence updating the summary information properties to follow standards. Summary information values update does not work with using C# and WIX but works fine when using third party mst creation tools like Installshield. So i think its possible to update summary info values with mst but i am unable to do it with wix + C#.

Comment: Interesting observation. If I use InstallShield it claims to let me change the SIS contents.  But when I apply the MST to the MSI using ORCA I can't see the changes.  If I then apply edit the MST in InstallShield it shows it.  This is beyond my knowledge.  Perhaps MichaelU or RobM can chime in with what they think is going on.  My instinct is that this is busy work and not really supported by the Windows Installer.